# Rails Capybara run a specific file (test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

Currently I have a huge integration test in a single file in my Rails 3 app in spec/main_spec.rb, and to run this test I simply do 'rake spec'. I want to begin to break this test up into differnt files. So lets say I create another test (file) called spec/another_spec.rb. How can I run this specific file? When I do...

```
bundle exec rake spec/another_spec.rb
```

Nother seems to happen...I don't get any errors, but I don't any feedback telling me whats passed or failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bundle exec rspec spec/another_spec.rb
```

or

```
rspec spec/another_spec.rb
```

Comment: Hmm...I am getting some failures in my tests when I run "bundle exec rspec spec/another_spec.rb" whereas when I run 'bundle exec rake spec' I do not. I'm wondering using your 'rspec' syntax I am not getting some of the appropriate config files.

Comment: You have test written in SPEC. To run spec test we use rspec. But in you have to run test only the we use 'rake test' command. Please check Rspec documentation before running test. Check this out https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails